# Delphi XE8 + Android - Tela de splash fecha antes da app ser carregada e mostra tela preta por muito tempo

Tags: android, delphi

Estou criando um APP em Delphi XE8, até aí tudo bem, o problema é que quando meu app vai ser carregado no Android, a tela de splash fecha muito cedo, o app não carregou ainda, então ele mostra uma tela preta antes do app abrir, por mais alguns segundos. Como resolver ou melhorar?

Comment: Isso ocorre no emulador ou no dispositivo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verifique o que foi implementado na criação do primeiro TForm, pode estar carregando algo no onCreate ou onShow, verifique a quantidade de formulários está a criar ao abrir a aplicação.

Caso nenhum deles resolver, verifique se isto ocorre somente neste seu ambiente, verifique em outro Android.